# difference between object and Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In the below code :-

```
 var x = { } ;
    console.log(typeof x);             // o/p is object
    console.log(x instanceof Object ); //o/p is true
```

If I use "**object**" instead of "**Object**" in the last line I get an error.Why is that so when the o/p of second line is **object** with a lowercase "o"?

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive... The name of the constructor is `Object`, not `object`.

Comment: `typeof` doesn't return the constructor that was used to create the instance, it simply returns a few predefined values depending on what argument it was used with.

Comment: For example `typeof ""` returns `'string'`, but there is no `string` object defined unless you define one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because there's no such thing as an 'object'. Typeof doesn't give you the class back - it gives you back the primitive type that it is. For example, `typeof "string"` gives you back "string".

The 'Object' is a constructor for an object 'primitive' - so a `new Object` gives you back an 'object' to work with.. but don't expect to be able to create a 'new object', as an 'object' doesn't exist as a constructor.

Answer (score 9):

You get an error because you haven't defined a variable named `object`. Attempting to read a variable that has not been declared is a *ReferenceError*.

The `Object` variable is native to the environment, and is pre-defined as the constructor function for plain objects. That's why it works when you do `instanceof Object`. Every native object in JavaScript is an instance of `Object`.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript is case sensitive "object" is essentially a variable that can hold anything. "Object" is an actual javascript type.