# What is the difference between Object and object type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What is the difference between `Object` and `object` in angular typescript

I get a tslint error:

> Don't use 'Object' as a type. Avoid using the `Object` type. Did you mean `object`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between object and Object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696297/difference-between-object-and-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @saurabh this is not what OP is asking about

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typescript-2-2-the-object-type

`object` represents any non-primitive type. The following types are considered to be primitive types in JavaScript:
string, 
boolean,
number,
bigint,
symbol,
null,
undefined.

> While `object` (lowercased) represents all non-primitive types, `Object`
>   (uppercased) describes functionality that is common to all JavaScript
>   objects.